# how to install window 8 64-bit on my 32-bit PC

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, windows-8-preview

I am currently running **Windows 7 32-bit**. I want to install **Windows 8 Developer Preview 64-bit**. Is it possible to install it with my existing Windows 7(32-bit) or is there any way to install **Windows 8 developer preview 64-bit** virtual on 32-bit PC or is there any to check if my PC is good for 64-bit OS.

I am having Intel Core 2 duo CPU E5300 2.60Ghz Processor, 2GB  RAM.

Comment: It's been a LONG time since I've seen a CPU that doesn't support x64.

Comment: What hardware do you have?

Answer (score 3):

Is your CPU 32-bit, or just your current install of Win7?  Regardless, you won't be able to install/run 64-bit software from within a 32-bit runtime.  This would most likely rule out the ability to perform an "upgrade install" as well.

A 32-bit operating system will boot/run the CPU in "protected mode", while 64-bit software requires that the CPU operate in "long mode".  In short, you need to install from a native 64-bit runtime.  Which you should be able to do by booting from the Win8 install disc, assuming your CPU is 64-bit capable.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU does use a 64-bit instruction set: http://ark.intel.com/products/35300/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E5300-%282M-Cache-2_60-GHz-800-MHz-FSB%29

So just install the OS according to it's normal instructions, though, with a Pentium-class processor, your experience will be far, far from optimal.

Comment: VMware and VirtualBox both support running 64-bit guests in a 32-bit host OS, provided the CPU itself is 64-bit-capable.

Comment: Oh, good to know. I'll update to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether or not your PC is "good" for a 64-bit OS, you'll have to find out which CPU you have, which you can do with System Properties (hit WINDOWS KEY+PAUSE).

Then look up the CPU that you're using and see if it supports x86-64.

If it does (most modern CPUs do) then you're good to go.

However, upgrading from a 32-bit OS to a 64-bit OS (even on a PC that supports 64-bit operating systems) is not supported as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2GB or 3GB RAM, even with a 64-bit capable processor, I would install the 32-bit of Windows 8 Pro. It just seems to be more responsive for some reason. Many others have had the same experience.

Comment: Other than personal experience do you have any metrics to display and argue your answer?

Answer (score -1):

he can't run any 64-bit os,because of his cpu doesn't meet hardware requirements for 64-bit os.that cpu doesn't support Hardware Virtualization Technology,as you can see on Intel's page above.

http://ark.intel.com/products/35300/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E5300-2M-Cache-2_60-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

Comment: Learn to do research better. **Instruction Set 64-bit** the CPU the author has fully supports 64-bit operating systems.  If you are going to reply to an old question, you better be 100% sure, your answer adds something useful.  While the CPU does not have support for visualization, numerous answers, already pointed that out.  The author was confused, so the section about a virtualized guest os, wasn't really part of the question.

Answer (score -2):

Checking the specs of the computer ([Intel core 2 duo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core_2)) you can certainly install a 64bit operating  system. But that doesn't necessarily mean that a 64bit OS is going to run smooth. For it to run smooth you will have to add atleast 2GB more ram ie, total 4GB. Also not more than 4GB as I don't think your PC can support more than 4GB.

### TO SUM IT UP :

```
You will be able to run a 64bit OS but to make it run smooth you will have to 
add 2GB more ram
```

Comment: This is a subjective statement. For example I have Windows 8 running on multiple systems with only 2GB of RAM, and it performs better than any version of Windows since XP.

Comment: @Joshua This is the preferred system requirements and not just my opinion.You will need 4GB ram only if you are running 64bit version of the OS